# Simple inquiry on a very small jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Here's a fairly newbish question: Testing out a simple function where it fades out on hover and fades back in on mouseout. Was playing around with parameters so please excuse how this doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but I just wanted to use 'opacity' in the parameter instead of hardcoding it (again, just to understand things). Here is my code:

```
$.fn.hoverImage = function(property) {
    //add event handler for each image (otherwise it will add the same event handler for all images all at once)
    this.each(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        //hover: first function is for mouseover, second is on mouseout
        img.hover(function() {      
            img.animate({
                property:0
            }, 200);
        }, function() {
            img.animate({
                property:1
            }, 200);
        });
    });
}
```

I call it doing:

```
$('.project-img').hoverImage('opacity');
```

If I write opacity as a string in the parameter it doesn't work, and if I don't put it in a string I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: opacity is not defined

Just want to know why. It does work if I use the word opacity in the plugin, just to clarify that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
{property: 0}
```

creates an object with a property named `property` with a value of `0`. In particular, it does *not* look up a variable named `property` and use that as the property name. If you wanted to do that, you'd have to break it out:

```
var obj = {};
obj[property] = 0;
/* use obj */
```

Compare this to using `obj.property`, which, too, would not use the `property` variable.

Comment: Thanks very much for this explanation! I assume then that 'opacity' is a recognized/already defined property in the jQuery animate function?

Comment: @Thomas: `opacity` is a property name that is accepted by jQuery, if that's what you were asking. It is not a variable that needs to be accessed like `property` was in your code, but rather one that could be accessed directly using `obj.opacity` or `obj["opacity"]` rather than `obj[property]` as we had to do for a generic `property`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators), because your property key is stored in a variable

```
$.fn.hoverImage = function (property) {
    //add event handler for each image (otherwise it will add the same event handler for all images all at once)
    this.each(function () {
        var img = $(this);
        //hover: first function is for mouseover, second is on mouseout
        img.hover(function () {
            var opts = {};
            opts[property] = 0;
            img.animate(opts, 200);
        }, function () {
            var opts = {};
            opts[property] = 1;
            img.animate(opts, 200);
        });
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Gy6N6/)

Comment: Thanks Arun! Very helpful fiddle, it clarified things for me.